# Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs'

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Error in Gridview paging when binding data 
Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs'

I have a databound event to dynamically add header. When the page first loads it loads fine. But when I try to click on next page , it errors at the databound event

```
Protected Sub OnDataBoundlvs(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim row As New GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal)
    Dim cell As New TableHeaderCell()
    cell.Text = "Network"
    cell.ColumnSpan = 1
    cell.CssClass = "FrozenHeader"
    row.Controls.Add(cell)
End Sub

Protected Sub OnPaging3(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles LVSGrid.PageIndexChanging
    LVSGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    LVSGrid.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you confirm that `LVSGrid` is defined as a `GridView` and not just as a `DataGrid` or something else?

Comment: I have a grid view and not a datagrid. I was able to resolve this issue by connecting to database and binding to a new datasource instead of using the same DataBind( ) method. The reason is I also have rowdatabound events and that was already binded with 1st page data and custom headers.

Comment: Rather late, but did you perhaps change `EventArgs` to `GridViewPageEventArgs` in OnPaging3? The system is probably sending `EventArgs` which it can't convert to `GridViewPageEventArgs`.